# Find the elements of a modulo multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How do you find the elements of a multiplicative group such as $\mathbb{Z}_6^{\times}$?

I know using the totient, $\Phi(6) = 2$, so there's 2 elements. I also understand that using the definition of groups and trial and error you could find out that 1 and 5 work but is there a easy way to find out the elements and conclude that $\mathbb{Z}_6^{\times} = \left \{ 1,5 \right \}$?

Comment: Are you asking "is there an easy way to find out which integers $1,\ldots,n-1$ are relatively prime to $n$?"

Comment: $1$ and $n{-}1$ are always in the group, so in this case it's *really* easy. But generally sieve on the factors  of $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no known easy way to find the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_m^\times$. Identifying these elements is an equivalent problem to factoring $m$, and rests in the complexity class $coNP\cap NP$. The particularly hard cases are when $m=pq$, although some cases (such as when all the prime factors are small relative to the product) can be easier given the right algorithm. You can read about progress on this problem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).